# Esperar a que los observables finalicen

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Cambie mi código de ngModel a ReactiveForms () para agregar validaciones. Pero ahora el valor de 'distrito' se muestra en el html solo a veces de forma aleatoria. Console log siempre  muestra el valor. Creo que es un problema con los http gets. Tengo que esperar a que termine 'this.ubigeoService.listaDistritos' antes de asignar un valor a 'distrito'. ¿Cómo podría resolver esto?

```
export class UbigeoService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }


  listarDepartamento(): Observable<string[]>{
    return this.http.get<string[]>(baseUrl+"/listaDepartamentos");
  }

  listaProvincias(paramDep:any): Observable<string[]>{
    return this.http.get<string[]>(baseUrl+"/listaProvincias/"+paramDep);
  }

  listaDistritos(paramDep:any,paramProv:any): Observable<Ubigeo[]>{
    return  this.http.get<Ubigeo[]>(baseUrl+"/listaDistritos/"+paramDep+"/"+paramProv);
  }


}
```

```
  busca(cliente: Cliente) {

    this.ubigeoService
      .listaProvincias(cliente.ubigeo?.departamento)
      .subscribe((response) => (this.provincias = response));

    this.ubigeoService
      .listaDistritos(
        cliente.ubigeo?.departamento,
        cliente.ubigeo?.provincia
      )
      .subscribe((response) => (this.distritos = response));

      this.clienteForm.patchValue({
        idCliente: cliente.idCliente,
        nombres: cliente.nombres,
        apellidos: cliente.apellidos,
        correo: cliente.correo,
        direccion: cliente.direccion,
        estado: cliente.estado,
        ubigeo: {
          idUbigeo: cliente.ubigeo?.idUbigeo,
          departamento: cliente.ubigeo?.departamento,
          provincia: cliente.ubigeo?.provincia,
          distrito: cliente.ubigeo?.distrito
        },
      });
      console.log(this.clienteForm.get('ubigeo').get('distrito').value);
  }
```

En los 3 select, cuando eligo un departamento, me trae las provincias con un evento change, asimismo esto para los distritos. Este es un Modal para actualizar clientes, solo he copiado la parte de los select. Al dar click en un boton editar, llama a la funcion 'busca' y rellena automáticamente los campos del modal con el contenido de una grilla.

```
                            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 5%" formGroupName="ubigeo">
                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <label for="id_act_departamento">Departamento</label>
                                    <select formControlName="departamento" (change)="cargaProvincia()"
                                        id="id_act_departamento" name="departamento" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">[Seleccione]</option>
                                        <option *ngFor="let aux of departamentos" value="{{ aux }}">
                                            {{ aux }}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <label for="id_act_provincia">Provincia</label>
                                    <select formControlName="provincia" (change)="cargaDistrito()" id="id_act_provincia"
                                        name="provincia" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">[Seleccione]</option>
                                        <option *ngFor="let aux of provincias" value="{{ aux }}">
                                            {{ aux }}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-4">
                                    <label for="id_act_distrito">Distrito</label>
                                    <select formControlName="idUbigeo" id="id_act_distrito" name="distrito"
                                        class="form-control">
                                        <option value="">[Seleccione]</option>
                                        <option *ngFor="let aux of distritos" value="{{ aux.idUbigeo }}">
                                            {{ aux.distrito }}
                                        </option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

UPDATE: Si agrego setTimeout al patchValue ya no ocurre el error.

```
setTimeout(() => {
        this.clienteForm.patchValue({
          idCliente: cliente.idCliente,
          nombres: cliente.nombres,
          apellidos: cliente.apellidos,
          correo: cliente.correo,
          direccion: cliente.direccion,
          estado: cliente.estado,
          ubigeo: {
            idUbigeo: cliente.ubigeo?.idUbigeo,
            departamento: cliente.ubigeo?.departamento,
            provincia: cliente.ubigeo?.provincia,
            distrito: cliente.ubigeo?.distrito
          },
        });
      }, 1000);
```

GitHub (Front, Back y BD)
https://github.com/frnkdmn/DAW2BackEndTemp
https://github.com/frnkdmn/DAW2FrontEndTemp

Comment: podrías agregar en tu pregunta el templete y el código que usaste en los servicios así me parece se entendería mejor el problema.PatchValue se usa solo para un subset de elementos de un FormGroup or FormArray,,SetValue requiere estructura exacta del objeto sin el resto del codigo no entiendo bien tu problema

Comment: quizás iniciando desde  ngOnInit() el this.clienteForm.patchValue

Comment: @nestdan trate de copiar todo el código posible para hacerlo mas entendible, quizas lo suba a github.

Comment: ok yo intentaria usar primero SetValue  para valores inicilaes  para todo el Form luego PatchValue para update en Nested ubigeo{} tambien tendria en cuenta ngOnInit() y revisaria si el uso del operador ? no afecta para esto usaria Disabling type checking using $any() lik para uso de PatchValue https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/setvalue-patchvalue-in-angular/

Comment: no había visto el uso de setTime probaste tambien con forkjoin --link>https://careydevelopment.us/blog/angular-use-forkjoin-to-wait-for-all-asynchronous-requests-to-complete-before-loading-a-page

Comment: replica el mismo error. forkJoin([
      this.ubigeoService
      .listaProvincias(cliente.ubigeo?.departamento),
      this.ubigeoService
      .listaDistritos(
        cliente.ubigeo?.departamento,
        cliente.ubigeo?.provincia
      )
    ]).subscribe((responses) => {
      this.provincias = responses[0];
      this.distritos = responses[1];
    }
    );

Comment: popie el codigo como respuesta con una modificacion se ve mejor el codigo como respuesta sigo buscando

Comment: le agregue a la respuesta que se ejecute con  ngOnInit(){}

Comment: ademas 

    En el HTML en el select -->value = "..." para string

    [ngValue] = "..." para objetos.

Comment: actualizado con los links de GitHub

Comment: modifique el forkJoin si no te sirve decime y elimino la respuesta la idea es recibir la respuesta en un objeto observable y poder usar tambien el el HTML como <div *ngIf='recibido$ | async as modelObjeto'><select (change)="onSelected($event<option *ngFor="let aux of modelObjeto"
            [value]=" aux.idUbigeo">{{ aux.distrito}}</option>
  </select></div>.....baje tu codigo no lo ejecute por problemas con @angular/form

Comment: Frank agregue comportamiento con observables para capturar cambios con BehaviorSubject saludos

Comment: Frank viste mi respuesta con Observables te sirvió?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un getter y un setter para detectar cuando las operaciones esten terminadas:

```javascript
_datosCargados = 0;
  set datosCargados(value: number) {
    this._datosCargados = value;
    console.log(value);
    //Si nuestro contador llega a tres, signifca que las 3 operaciones
    // que definimos terminaron su carga.
    if (this._datosCargados === 3) this.crearFormulario();
  }

  get datosCargados() {
    return this._datosCargados;
  }
  
  //Creamos una cache de los datos para acceder a ellos posteriormente. 
  departamentos = [];
  provincias = [];
  distritos = [];

  constructor(private ubigeoService: UbigeoService) {}
  
  //Ejecutamos todo cuando el componente este listo. 
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ubigeoService.listarDepartamento().subscribe((x) => {
      this.departamentos = x;
      this.datosCargados++;
      this.carga('departamentos');
    });
    this.ubigeoService.listaProvincias({}).subscribe((x) => {
      this.provincias = x;
      this.datosCargados++;
      this.carga('provincias');
    });
    this.ubigeoService.listaDistritos(null, null).subscribe((x) => {
      this.distritos = x;
      this.datosCargados++;
      this.carga('distritos');
    });
  }

  leyenda = '....Cargando departamentos, provincias, distritos';
  carga = (texto) => (this.leyenda = this.leyenda.replace(texto, ''));
  crearFormulario() {
    this.leyenda = 'Se muestra el formulario';
  }
```

La carga podría ser a solicitud (al desplegar cada una de las opciones ), pero en lo personal prefiero cargar todos los datos, siempre y cuando no representen un problema por el tamaño.

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aquí](https://angular-ivy-xvtxqt.stackblitz.io)

> Los observables son operaciones asincronas y la forma en que se ejecutan no corresponde al orden en que son escritas, depende del tiempo de respuesta del servidor, tráfico en la red, y demás chunches que hay en la red. Hay que escribir código extra para asegurarse de que la operación esta terminada antes de utilizar sus datos, de ahí la estructura que te propongo.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// crud-cliente.component.ts
        distritos$!:Observable<Ubigeo[]>
        private distritoSelectedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
        userSelectedAction$ = this.distritoSelectedSubject.asObservable();
        
        onSelected(event: Event): void {
            // event:InputEvent??
            // or <HTMLInputElement>event.target
            let userName = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
            this.distritoSelectedSubject.next(userName)
        
          }
        
        cargaDistrito() {
            let dep = this.clienteForm.get('ubigeo').get('departamento').value
            let pro = this.clienteForm.get('ubigeo').get('provincia').value
            if(!dep || !pro) return
          this.distritos$=  this.ubigeoService
              .listaDistritos(dep, pro)
              .pipe(
                tap(data=>console.log('distitos',JSON.stringify(data))),
                catchError(err => throwError('Error occurred'))
              )
          }
        busca(cliente: Cliente) {
        
            ......
        .......
              this.distritos$= this.ubigeoService
              .listaDistritos(
                cliente.ubigeo?.departamento,
                cliente.ubigeo?.provincia
              )
              .pipe(
                tap(data=>console.log('distitos',JSON.stringify(data))),
                catchError(err => throwError('Error occurred'))
              )
        .....
        .....
        }
//para ver cambios 
            this.clienteForm.get('ubigeo').get('departamento').
                valueChanges.subscribe(  
                  (      value: any)=> {  
                     console.log(JSON.stringify(value));  
                  }  
               );  
                           ngOnInit(){
                             this.ubigeoService
                          .listarDepartamento()
                          .subscribe((response) => (this.departamentos = response));
                        this.clienteForm = this.fb.group({
                          idCliente: [0],
                          nombres: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
                          apellidos: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
                          correo: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.email]],
                          direccion: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(20)]],
                          estado: [1],
                          ubigeo: this.fb.group({
                            idUbigeo: ['', [Validators.required]],
                            departamento: ['', [Validators.required]],
                            provincia: ['', [Validators.required]],
                            distrito: [''],
                          }),
                        });
                        
                            recibido$= forkJoin([
                            this.ubigeoService .listaProvincias
                        (cliente.ubigeo?.departamento),
                         this.ubigeoService .listaDistritos
                         ( cliente.ubigeo?.departamento, cliente.ubigeo?.provincia ) ])
                          ]).pipe(
                           
                            map(([provincias,distritos ]) => ({
                             // objetoM segun modelo deseado
                            }) as objetoM)
                          )
                          // html
                          {{recibidos$ | async | json}
                        }
```

```html
// crud-cliente.component.html
        <h1>Seleccionaste :{{distritoSelectedAction$ | async | json}}</h1>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4" *ngIf='distritos$ |async as distritos'>
                                            <label for="id_reg_distrito">Distrito</label>
        <select formControlName="idUbigeo" id="id_reg_distrito" name="distrito"
                          class="form-control">
                           (change)="onSelected($event)"
                             <option value="">[Seleccione]</option>
            <option *ngFor="let aux of distritos" value=" aux.idUbigeo ">
                                                    {{ aux.distrito }}
                               </option>
          </select>
                            <div *ngIf="clienteForm.get('ubigeo').get('idUbigeo').invalid && (clienteForm.get('ubigeo').get('idUbigeo').dirty || clienteForm.get('ubigeo').get('idUbigeo').touched)"
                                            class="alert alert-danger" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                                <div *ngIf="clienteForm.get('ubigeo').get('idUbigeo').errors.required">Distrito es requerido.</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta? Si vas a pedir aclaración o hacer comentarios, evita usar el espacio de respuestas para eso. Te sugiero que elimines esta **no respuesta**. Saludos